# Derivative of $\log^{k}(x)$

Tags: calculus

What is the derivative of $f(x)= \log^{k}x$ where $k$ is a positive integer?

**Update:**

Hello I have found that $\log^k n$ = $(\log n)^k$

(Thomas H. Cormen, Introduction to Algorithms (2ed) p. 53 )

Comment: By $\log^k(x)$, do you mean $(\log x)^k$ or the log-base-$k$ of $x$?

Comment: @Isaac: $k$ is an exponent.

Comment: @PEV: How do you know?  $\log^k$ is used to denote the base-$k$ logarithm function in some places.

Comment: It could be $log\circ\log\circ\dots\circ\log$, where $\log$ is iterated $k$ times.

Comment: as Andres Caicedo said, that notation is reserved for iterating the function n times rather than exponentiation. What he really means is $(\log x)^k$

Comment: I don't agree that it's "reserved" for that meaning. But it could mean that, as well as $(\log x)^k$.

Comment: @Arjang: while in most cases we use exponents like that to denote composition, *some* functions follow a different convention; e.g., $\sin^2(x)$ almost invariably means $(\sin x)^2$, and almost never $\sin(\sin(x))$. Trig and hyperbolic functions follow the "usual power, not composition" convention. While $\log$ and $\ln$ don't usually follow the same convention as trig functions, I've seen it more than once or twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $k$ is an exponent, use the chain rule, $f(x) = g(h(x))$, $\frac{d f}{d x} = \frac{d g}{d h} \frac{d h}{d x}$. In this case we have $g(h) = h^k$ and $h(x) = \log x$.

$$\frac{d}{dx} (\log x)^k = \frac{d}{d h} \left(h^k\right) \frac{d}{d x} \left(\log x \right) = k h^{k-1} \frac{d}{dx} \log x = k (\log x)^{k-1} \frac{d}{dx} \log x$$

Now, if $\log$ is the natural logarithm you get:

$$\frac{d}{dx} (\log x)^k = \frac{k}{x} (\log x)^{k-1}$$

If $\log$ is the base $b$ logarithm you get $\log x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$ (denoting the natural logarithm by $\ln$):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \log^k x = k (\log x)^{k-1} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\ln x}{\ln b} = k \frac{(\ln x)^{k-1}}{(\ln b)^{k-1}} \frac{1}{x \ln b} = k \frac{(\ln x)^{k-1}}{x (\ln b)^k}$$

EDIT: Given your source you probably want to use $b = 2$ in the formula above.

EDIT2: Changed notation from $\log^k x$ to $(\log x)^k$ for clarity.

Another way to derive the equation above is to use the product rule $f(x) = f_1(x)f_2(x)$, $f'(x) = f_1'(x)f_2(x) + f_1(x)f_2'(x)$. Since $f(x) = (\log x)^k = \log x \log x \cdots \log x$. Now, when you derive you get one term for every factor in the product, each term containing the derivative once. All the terms are equal so you can simply multiply by the number of terms ($k$) instead:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dx} \left(\log x \right)^k = \left(\frac{d}{dx}  \log x \right) \log x \cdots \log x \log x + \dots + \log x \log x \cdots \log x \left( \frac{d}{dx} \ \log x \right) = \\ 
= k \left( \frac{d}{dx} \log x \right) (\log x)^{k-1}
\end{aligned}$$

which is the same expression as obtained above.

Comment: Thank you. Why if log is base b is different if base 10 please? 

"If $\log$ is the base $b$ logarithm you get $\log x = \frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$ (denoting the natural logarithm by $\ln$):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \log^k x = k (\log x)^{k-1} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\ln x}{\ln b} = k \frac{(\ln x)^{k-1}}{(\ln b)^{k-1}} \frac{1}{x \ln b} = k \frac{(\ln x)^{k-1}}{x (\ln b)^k}$$"

Comment: @Avra, sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

Use the chain rule (extra characters).