# How to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\log(n)^k}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> How to find 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\log(n)^k}\ \ ?$$

I know the limit is infinity, but I can't manage to do it step by step using l'Hopital. Could someone explain how it is done?

Comment: Why won't you simply write $$\frac n{(\log n)^k}\;?$$ This must make things really simpler.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I guess that only the $n$ is raised to the power $k$ as in $log [(n)^k]$ and not the entire $log (n)$

Comment: After simplifying, as @DonAntonio suggested, check https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-find-the-limit-of-ln-n-n-as-n-approaches-infinity

Comment: @NoChance Perhaps so...and then the limit is even simpler!

Comment: You are true, I should have written $$\frac{n}{\log(n)^k},\qquad\mbox{ as $n\to\infty$}.$$ my problem is to apply the derivate to  $log(n)^k$ as the derivative is another logarithm https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18069/derivative-of-logkx so, how can I simplificate to solve the limit?

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital's Rule shows $\frac {e^{x}} {x^{k}} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Put $x =\log \, n$.

Comment: But the top part would be $e^x$ instead of $x$ is it relevant for the limit?